# Can a US Presidential election ever be held earlier in a President's term?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election

Are there circumstances in United States where a presidential election and subsequent inauguration can be held before the end of the president's term?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### No (barring really unusual circumstances).

The date of the Presidential election is fixed by Congress, and inauguration day is set by the [Twentieth Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twentieth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution).  If a President dies (or otherwise leaves office) during their term, their VP takes the oath of office and serves out the rest of the term - it is not extended in any way.

This means that *all* Presidential elections happen during the last few months of the previous President's term, and the inauguration happens on the last day of the their term (which is also the first day of the new term).

The only time this would get weird is if the current Vice President ran for President,  won, and the current President died between the election day and the VP's inauguration day.  In that case, following the rules of succession, the VP would be sworn in as President immediately (without a formal inauguration), to serve out the remainder of their predecessor's term.  Then they would be sworn in *again* on their own inauguration day.  <sub>(This would not prevent them from running for a second term in their own right, since the few weeks would be less than the "more than two years" specified in the [Twenty-second Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-second_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution).</sub>

Comment: I had to look it up to be sure, but in that hypothetical [the VP could still serve 2 additional full terms](https://constitutioncenter.org/interactive-constitution/amendments/amendment-xxii) as president.

Comment: @BradC - I was *just* adding that to the answer :)

Comment: While true, the wierd exception doesn't seem to apply to the OP's question, as it wouldn't move the election or inauguration at all.  For instance Lyndon Johnson, who served a bit more than a year of Kennedy's term, then was elected to a full 4-year term.  And AFAIK, VPs who've replaced a President who died in office (or resigned) have never had formal inaugurations, just a quiet oath-taking.

Comment: @jamesqf - The point of the discussing that exception was *exactly* that it wouldn't move the dates.  I clarified the swearing in vs inauguration, though.